# Histogram Equalization without openCV, C++

Tags: c++, histogram

I'm trying to implement histogram equalization to improve the contrast in a grayscale image, but no matter what I do, my program only seems to make the image overall darker. Can someone point me in the right direction? Here's the code I'm working with right now, as well as some sample images

```
void calcHisto(int w, int h, ifstream& input_1, ofstream& output_1) {

    int tmp = w * h;
    double size = (double)tmp;
    double grayVal[256] = { }; //count of Gray levels 0-255
     double PDF[256] = { };
    double CDF[256] = { };
    double equalized[256] = { };

    int** in_matrix_ch1 = new int* [h]; //Create matrix for grayVals
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
        in_matrix_ch1[i] = new int[w];
    for (int i_h = 0; i_h < h; i_h++) {
        for (int i_w = 0; i_w < w; i_w++) {
            char g;     //Determine a pixel's gray value
            input_1.get(g);
            in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w] = (int)g;

        }
    }
    for (int i_h = 0; i_h < h; i_h++) {
        for (int i_w = 0; i_w < w; i_w++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) { //Increment the count value for the appropriate grayVal
                if (in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w] == i) { //If the grayVal at pixel = an index, increment that index
                    grayVal[i]++;  //If grayVal at pixel = i, increment grayVal[i]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PDF[0] = grayVal[0] / size;
    CDF[0] = PDF[0];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
        PDF[i] = grayVal[i] / size;
        CDF[i] = PDF[i] + PDF[i - 1];
        equalized[i] = round(255 * CDF[i]);

    }

    for (int i_h = 0; i_h < h; i_h++) {
        for (int i_w = 0; i_w < w; i_w++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
                if (in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w] == i) { //If the grayVal at this pixel is equal to an index,
                    in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w] = equalized[i]; //Set the grayVal at this pixel to the equalized value of that index
                }
            }
            output_1 << (char)in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w];
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ifstream input_1;
    ofstream output_1;
    string header;

    if (argc > 2) {
        // file name 
        input_1.open(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
        output_1.open(argv[2], ios::out | ios::binary);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "argv[1] for reading and argv[2] for writing");
        exit(0);
    }
    getline(input_1, header);

    //header w,h extract
    string s_w, s_h;
    s_w = header.substr(3, 3);
    s_h = header.substr(7, 3);
    int w = stoi(s_w), h = stoi(s_h);

    output_1 << header << endl;
    calcHisto(w, h, input_1, output_1);

    input_1.close();
    output_1.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Im working with a few .pgm images, and here's an example of the original image, vs. the result I get:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXX8B.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B47vT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the wikipedia ( [Histogram Equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) ):

- I have improbed histogram calculation performance, by removing inner loop.
- PDF/CDF computation is broken (according to the wikipedia formula). PDF is no needed. Please check my version below.
- I don't see cdfmin computation in your code.

  ```
   void calcHisto(int w, int h, ifstream& input_1, ofstream& output_1) {
   int tmp = w * h;
   double size = (double)tmp;
   double grayVal[256] = { }; //count of Gray levels 0-255
   double CDF[256] = { };
   double equalized[256] = { };

   int** in_matrix_ch1 = new int* [h]; //Create matrix for grayVals
   for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
       in_matrix_ch1[i] = new int[w];

   for (int i_h = 0; i_h < h; i_h++) {
       for (int i_w = 0; i_w < w; i_w++) {
           char g;     //Determine a pixel's gray value
           input_1.get(g);
           in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w] = (unsigned char)g;
           grayVal[(unsigned char)g]++;
       }
   }

   CDF[0] = grayVal[0];
   int cdfmin = CDF[0];
   for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
       CDF[i] = CDF[i - 1] + grayVal[i];
       if (cdfmin == 0)
           cdfmin = CDF[i];
   }


   for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
       equalized[i] = std::round( 255 * (CDF[i] - cdfmin) / (size - cdfmin));

   for (int i_h = 0; i_h < h; i_h++) {
       for (int i_w = 0; i_w < w; i_w++) {
           int input_color = in_matrix_ch1[i_h][i_w];
           int output_color = equalized[input_color];
           output_1 << (char)output_color;
       }
   }

   //TODO: release memory or use e.g: vector
  }
  ```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9CdY.png)